# Using Gradle Source Sets to Swap resources directory between dev/prod

Tags: java, gradle, source-sets

I have Java application that uses Gradle.  Currently my resources directory contains [Typesafe Config](https://github.com/typesafehub/config) and [Log4J](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) configuration files.

Both of these files would have different settings based on whether my application is built for dev or production.  For example, I would want Log4J to only log at the INFO level in production.

I am unable to use environment variables to swap these settings, and my only option is doing it through these resource files.

Ideally I'd like to be able to have 2 source sets in my Gradle config--one for dev (main) and one for prod--and have Gradle build a jar for each of these source sets.  The main source set would continue to use src/main/resources as the resource directory, and the prod source set would use src/main/resources-prod as the resource directory.

I'm fine with these resource directories are in other locations--the above is just an example.

Right now, the only custom portions of my Gradle config are the following (outside of adding compile dependencies):

```
task buildZip(type: Zip) {
    from compileJava
    from processResources
    into('lib') {
        from configurations.runtime
    }
}

build.dependsOn buildZip
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: what did you end up doing for this?